# How to show user consent prompt when calling GetAccessTokenForUserAsync method?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

Questions relating to the `AADSTS65001` error mentioned here are all over the internet but none of the solutions I tried have worked.

We have registrations in our Azure tenant for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API application and a UI application. The API requires authorization and I am trying to implement a solution to authorize the API on behalf of the user when someone signs into the UI.

When I build the UI code, sign-in, and go to a page that calls the API, I get the following error which happens during call of `ITokenAcquisition`'s `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` method. However, I can bypass this error by deleting the auth cookie and refreshing the page:

```
MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string authenticationScheme, string tenantId, string userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
```

After bypassing the error above I get a new one, again occurring during `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` method call:

```
MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx' named 'x y z'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
Trace ID: xxx
Correlation ID: xxx
Timestamp: 2021-10-14 15:43:50Z
Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ThrowServerException(HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)

MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string authenticationScheme, string tenantId, string userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
```

Since I've done this before, I would expect the user to get a consent prompt to the API app, but it's just this error. I've verified with an admin that in *Azure AD > Enterprise applications > User Settings > Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf* option is enabled:

[image]

Additionally, I gave admin consent to permissions on both apps (whether or not the permissions require it) but that error persists.

The only way to at least not get the `AADSTS65001` error was to go into *API app registration > Expose an API > Add a client application* and add the `ClientId` of the UI app. But then the user doesn't get the prompt to consent.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause of this issue is due to permissions. When the user consents the permission, essentially the permissions are granted to the service principle (enterprises application) corresponded to the AD App that the user logged in, navigate to the enterprise application corresponded to the AD App in the portal.

In the permissions you will find the permissions that the user consented. When the same user logins into the app again it will not promote the user to consent the same permissions again by default, because the permissions have already granted to the service principal, just if there are new permissions added to the AD App. Lastly it will then promote the user to consent the new permissions again.

Second way to resolve this issue:
Make sure your Azure AD setting allows adding the app. There are couple of properties under Azure AD Application:

- Manage
- User setting that affect how the app is registered.
  Someone in your organization may have turned app registration off altogether, or limited the options. You could check these settings out.

Third option would be to be sure to ask a global admin to login once.